# Kendo UI Without Server Side been hosted

Tags: user-interface, twitter, kendo-ui

OK Planing to Build small twitter App with Kendo UI . just wondering if that mean part of the app will be hosted in my server in order to get that work ?

I don't want host any part of the app at the server . i want this App to work directly Forward and backward from the app at user Device to twitter API

Please don't tell me it's just script will be hosted and the App that going to be created with Phonegap or whatever is just a Browser . Please don't tell me that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question right but you can create a JavaScript only (no-server side code required) twitter client. You can embed all required JavaScript files and deploy them using PhoneGap.